# Entity Framework and N-Tier

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, n-tier-architecture

Having an architecture problem. I am trying to split out logical tiers into physical tiers and having a little trouble. Here is the way I would like things set up:

- Entities - A DLL. My POCO classes. No depndencies.
- DAL - A DLL. Contains the Model and a DbContext. Relies on Entities.
- BLL - A DLL. Contains CRUD functions. Relies on DAL and Entities
- UI - A Web Site Project. Speaks to BLL.

My problem is that in the BLL, I do something like:

```
 ''' <summary>
''' The repository
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private context As MyContext

''' <summary>
''' Instantiate the business layer
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub New()
    context = New MyContext()
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Insert a general retrieve into the database
''' </summary>
''' <param name="myEntity">The entity to insert</param>
''' <returns>The id of the entity added</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function Create(ByVal myEntity As myEntity) As String
    Try
        context.myEntity.Add(myEntity )
        context.SaveChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return myEntity.id
End Function
```

But in order to call Add on my entity I need a reference to the EntityFramework.dll because my context inherits from DbContext. I don't see how to avoid this without creating a repository, which seems like an unecessary additional layer of abstraction, plus I thought I did not need ti with DbContext.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your DAL can define interface implemented by your derived context and factory for your context. BLL will use only interface and factory.

Comment: Sorry, I need a little more detail. I am not sure i understand all the concepts you are referencing.

Comment: So if my context is called myDbContext, which inherits from DbContext, I should have an ImyDbContext, and the actual context inherits from DbContext and implements ImyDbContext. I'll have to try and implement this in the morning.

Comment: I am stuck here. I created an interface, but the interface still relies in IDbSet, which requires the EntityFramework DLL in the business layer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck on this topic you should have a look at the N-Tier Entity Framework available on CodePlex: http://ntieref.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've pretty much worked out how to do this, but  will definitely take a look at that project to help clean things up.